# meta tag to correct Â®

Tags: html, encoding, character-encoding, meta-tags

I'm having some trouble getting a special character properly encoded.

`Â®` keeps coming through instead of the registered trademark symbol. I've tried changing the meta tag to UTF-8 and Windows-1252, but it still comes through in the encoded format?  Can I add a meta tag to fix this?

Comment: Is the page ran with some PHP on it? Is your DOCTYPE clearly specified? `<meta charset="utf-8">`, did you [save your file with the proper encoding too](http://i.imgur.com/dHbA3J2.jpg)? For such special characters, the encoding `ISO-8859-1` might do the job too.

Comment: Same guess: You forget to save tha file with correct encoding.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure to **save your file with the proper encoding**:

[image].

Here is an example; on the **left side**, the file is saved with `Window-1252` encoding.
On the **right side**, it's saved with `UTF-8` encoding
[image]

---

## HTML options

For such characters, encoding with `ISO-8859-1` might do it too, but `UTF-8` is greatly encouraged.

Make sure your `DOCTYPE` is clearly defined : `<!DOCTYPE HTML>`.

Make sure your `meta` tag is written properly: `<meta charset="UTF-8">`.

---

## PHP options

If you use PHP within your page, add the following at the beginning of the page:

`<?php header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8'); ?>`

---

If the content is output from a database, you might want to use `utf8_encode()` to encode different encodings to `UTF-8`

> [**utf8_encode()**](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.utf8-encode.php)
>
> Encodes an ISO-8859-1 string to UTF-8

Answer (score 2):

The information about encoding should correspond to the actual encoding. So instead of making guesses and trial and error, find out what the encoding really is. It seems to be UTF-8, and if declaring UTF-8 in a `meta` tag does not help, the probable culprit is an HTTP header that the server sends and that declares a different encoding, trumping the `meta` tag. Use e.g. [an HTTP header viewer](http://www.rexswain.com/httpview.html) to check out the situation.

If the server announces iso-8859-1 or windows-1252 and if you cannot change this, then you just have to use that encoding instead of UTF-8. Then save the page in your authoring program as windows-1252 encoded.